# check if the array values are in ascending order

Tags: c

I have some problems with my code, I need to check if the values on the array are in ascending order. Everything fine, until the user input the lenght of array 9 and the array: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 it somehow shows that the array is not in ascending order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,flag,a[50];
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        flag=0;
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("The array values are in ascending order");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The array values are not in ascending order");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Tip: `if(flag==0)` could have been written `if (!flag)`. You could even use `if (flag)` by swapping the "then" and "else" blocks.

Comment: Tip: `flag=0;` should be outside of the loop. There's no reason to do it more than once.

Comment: Tip: If you pull numbers out of your butt, you're doing something wrong. `int a[50];` should be `int a[n];`. Obviously, this should be done after initializing `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about `9` or 9 elements. You just got lucky when it did work.

The problem is that `for(i=0; i<n; ++i)` performs one pass too many. You end up comparing `9` (`a[n-1]`) against whatever follows it (`a[(n-1)+1]`), except that element (`a[n]`) has never been initialized.

Replace

```c
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)     // n - 0 = n comparisons. XXX
```

with

```c
for(i=0; i<n-1; ++i)   // (n-1) - 0 = n-1 comparisons.
```

or

```c
for(i=1; i<n; ++i)     // n - 1 = n-1 comparisons.
```

The latter requires adjusting the condition in the if statement to look behind.